# mysql organizando entradas no banco

Tags: mysql, sql, stack

Queria saber se é possível reordenar as entradas de uma tabela no mysql, sobreescrevendo as entradas deletadas, e sem quebrar as outras tabelas.
Se for possível, qual o comando usaria e que me mostre algum exemplo.

Por exemplo:
Na tabela X tem os dados:

```
+----+----------+
| ID | coluna 1 |
+----+----------+
| 1  | exemplo  |
| 2  | exemplo  |
| 3  |          | (apagado)
| 4  | exemplo  |
| 5  |          | (apagado)
| 6  | exemplo  |
+----+----------+
```

Reordenando a tabela:

```
+----+----------+
| ID | coluna 1 |
+----+----------+
| 1  | exemplo  |
| 2  | exemplo  |
| 3  | exemplo  |
| 4  | exemplo  |
+----+----------+
```

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acredito que não seja possível, mas você pode seta o valor a cada exclusão.

ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

Comment: user2321982, eu sei que em javascript é possível realinhar uma pilha em um array, mas não sei se no mysql seria possível fazer esse procedimento.

Comment: Vou pesquisar mais sobre o problema.
Obrigado por ter respondido.

Answer (score 2):

Possível é, mas não é tão fácil como em uma pilha, se imaginarmos uma pilha, fisicamente, em um ambiente que exista gravidade, se você tirar qualquer elemento dela, os que estão acima, logicamente irão "cair" e ocupar novas posições. Uma tabela não é uma pilha...

Respondendo a sua pergunta:

O modo mais fácil que exista seria excluir a coluna ID e recriar a mesma.

```
alter table X drop column ID; /*Exclui-se a coluna*/
alter table X add column ID integer not null auto_increment primary key;
```

Só tem um problema em fazer isso, se sua tabela possui FK (*Foreign Keys*) você não conseguirá deletar a coluna sem perder as referencias nas outras tabelas.

Se você precisa manter a referência, recomendo utilizar um procedimento armazenado (*Stored Procedure*), por exemplo, uma vez por semana, ou por mês...

A Stored Procedure precisaria ter um **cursor** e um **contador**. O cursor serviria para você percorrer a tabela (nada mais é do que um SELECT) e o contador vai conter o valor do ID esperado, que nada mais é do que o valor do ID que é esperado (ou seja, o ID do registro anterior + 1). Dentro do loop do cursor, você faz a verificação (IF) se o ID é igual ao valor do contador, se for beleza, você soma 1 ao contador e segue o loop, se não for você faz um update naquela linha, informa que o ID dela agora é o valor do contador e ai segue o processo (soma um ao contador e segue o loop)

Só lembrando que isso é um custo muito alto para o banco de dados (custo => Processamento), gostaria de saber por qual motivo você deseja fazer isso...

Alguns pontos sobre esta reordenação:

- **ID** é abreviação de **IDentity** ou **IDentification**, não faz sentido você ficar modificando este campo. Imagina que cada vez que morre uma pessoa, o Governo deseja atualizar o CPF e/ou o RG de todos os outros que continuaram vivos ? Já pensou no caos ?
- Imagina que você tem uma tabela com 10k (mil) registros. Você apaga o 1, fazendo do último modo que falei, você teria 9999 UPDATES, porque todos ficariam errados (você atualiza o 2 pra 1, o 3 pra 2... o 10000 pra 9999), pode ter certeza que você ter um mega LOCK no seu banco de dados e muitos problemas de I/O.
- Se você usa o ID para alguma referência externa (Seja para gerar links no seu site, acesso a relatório por outro sistema, o que seja), ao fazer isso, como que você atualizar no outro local que está salvo, que você atualizou na sua tabela para que a referência não se perca ?
- Você vai usar muito processador e memória do seu servidor só pra deixar os registros "organizados".
- Recomendo que você não exclua/remova os registros do banco, e sim marque-os (flag) como inativo, assim você tem eles salvos na sua base, mas seu sistema sabe que não é para utilizar, fazendo isso você pode restaurar algum registro facilmente, e ainda não tem esse problema de "organização".